# My motion tracking scene is offset from the footage

Tags: tracking

[image: misaligned motion tracking footage]

I have a scene motion tracked with a solve error of 0.41 pixels, and it seems to move correctly, however, the entire scene is weirdly offset from the actual footage, as if the camera's origin is the bottom left corner of the view instead of the center. I experience this problem with every scene I try to motion track, and I am not sure what is causing the problem. I have already tried setting the floor/wall/origin with Blender's built-in scene reconstruction tools, but that seems to be where the problem starts. Setting up the tracking scene appears to just not correctly set the scene up, resulting in a weird offset. Is there a way to re-offset it so that the markers align correctly with the footage?

edit: after some trial-and-error, ive found that the camera lens shift x and y can be used to manually correct this issue, however, it appears to be a very imprecise method. i need to know what causes the issue in the first place still so it can hopefully be fixed.